# Extend already build tensorflow model by additional input and layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I try to extend one of my alread build models with another layer to sum the substraction of the previous output of the model and an additional input. All my tries can be summarized using the Lambda-layer:

```
    new_input = Input(shape=(20, 3))
    sub_layer = Lambda(lambda x: Reshape((20,1))(backend.sum(x[0] - x[1], axis=-1)))((model.output,new_input))
    model = Model(inputs=[model.input, new_input], outputs=sub_layer.output)
```

But no matter what I do I always receive this error:

```
Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 20, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.reshape/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'tf.reshape'") of unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your pretrained model looks like, but you can try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(3)(outputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((20,3))(outputs)
model1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

new_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(20, 3))
sub_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.layers.Reshape((20,1))(tf.keras.backend.sum(x[0] - x[1], axis=-1)))((model1.output,new_input))
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[model1.input, new_input], outputs=sub_layer)
print(model2.summary())
```

```
Model: "model_4"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_7 (InputLayer)           [(None, 10)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 20)           220         ['input_7[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVector)  (None, 3, 20)       0           ['dense_3[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 reshape (Reshape)              (None, 20, 3)        0           ['repeat_vector_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 input_8 (InputLayer)           [(None, 20, 3)]      0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 lambda_3 (Lambda)              (None, 20, 1)        0           ['reshape[0][0]',                
                                                                  'input_8[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 220
Trainable params: 220
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: IDK what u have done differently, but it works. I think it has something to do with the imports. Maybe I mixed something from old Keras with TensorFlow Keras. Thank you again. ;)

Comment: The difference is especially that you used `sub_layer.output`  instead of `sub_layer` @lkaupp

Comment: Although used sub_layer without the output. Have a new error, now: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() . Somewhere i compare some tensors in the wrong way, with my predict i guess

Comment: It could also be this part `x[0] - x[1]`, but it is really hard to say. Anyway, that is the proper to connect the two models.

Comment: Tried the same thing with a custom layer and two inputs to the call function, the error persists. But, usually, it is possible to subtract two tensors from each other. - Tried tf.print to stdout, but it seems that predict will not enter the layer at all. Is it a problem to use predict different shaped inputs on predict? In my case (10k,10,12)(10k,20,3)?

Comment: Well yeah it is a problem if you defined a specific input shape

Comment: Seems it is thrown by # If batch_size is not passed but steps is, calculate from the input data.
    # Default to 32 for backwards compat.
    if not batch_size:
      batch_size = int(math.ceil(num_samples / steps)) if steps else 32 (\keras\engine\data_adapter.py). So the resampling to the batchsize is the reason, but i can assure that both sets are taken from a dataset with batchsize 32...

Comment: Found my mistake! If you have 2 inputs, just use an array in your prediction model.predict([input1,input2]). Works like a charm! cheers. Thank you again!